# Open APIs or libraries for creating thumbnails? (.psd, .pdf, .docx)

Tags: api, thumbnails, libraries, preview

Is there any easy way to create thumbnails/previews for varies filetypes? Specifically .psd, .pdf and the office formats (.doc/docx .xls etc.) I've googled and found nothing... :(

Answer (score 0):

Not a clean solution, but you can use these APIs from ConvertAPI -

https://www.mashape.com/convertapi/word2pdf-1
https://www.mashape.com/convertapi/powerpoint2pdf
https://www.mashape.com/convertapi/excel2pdf

Then convert them to an image -

https://www.mashape.com/convertapi/pdf2image

EDIT (in response to comment below):  Mashape is an API Marketplace that lets developers discover, consume, distribute, and monetize APIs.  Being a marketplace, the "seller" of APIs can decide if they want to offer their APIs for free, or paid.  You can check out more about Mashape in http://mashape.com/howitworks

Comment: I don't really understand mashape.com.. Is it forever-free? Any limits?